# How much memory a goal uses?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

In Swi-Prolog I can enclose a goal in `time/1` to see how much CPU time a goal takes.

How do I do use `statistics/2` correctly to see how much RAM a goal takes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interestingly, **you can't**.

For more information, please see this issue:

https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/issues/290

If you need this functionality, please participate in this discussion and outline your use case. It may help to implement this feature correctly, or to ensure that an alternative is available that does what you need.

Comment: Okay - good to know. 
Ill have a rethink and try add to that discussion.